# Multitanancy using typegoose , nestjs framework

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, typegoose

I am trying to build multitenancy functionality, each tenant will have its own database.
Is this possible to create dynamically the connections using typegoose?

Comment: Me too I'm building a multitenancy app using mongodb, I used this tutorial https://github.com/ismaeil-shajar/multitenancy/tree/roles-policies Hope it helps

Comment: Manuvo  but he doesn't use typegoose  and when used typegoose then multitenancy didn't acheived.

Comment: I am not quite sure what this question means, but typegoose supports creating models on different connections (which in mongoose has just one database assigned) with [`existingConnection`](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/decorators/model-options/#existingconnection), which can be passed via the `@modelOptions` decorator or the `getModelForClass` call.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying with express only and next time I have plan to try with nestjs. But you can get idea how tenancy is working with typegoose. I succeeded. Please check this [repository](https://github.com/grid-momenta/template-express-saas).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).